# Unit testing gui with gtk c#

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

How do I unit test gtk C#.
When I launch the gui it controls the thread. I have little experience in testing UI so any help would be appreciated. Also I'm using gtk (c#) for the first time.

This is what I am trying.

```
    [TestFixture]
public class AddEmployeeWindowTest
{
    private AddEmployee window;
    private AddEmployeePresenter presenter;
    private TransactionContainer container;

     [Test]
    public void CreateWindow()
    {
        Application.Init();
        window = new AddEmployee();
        window.Show();
        Application.Run();
        window.Destroy();
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

My goal is to check when text boxes are updated and update the presenter accordingly.
Using Rider-linux so Windows Forms are not an option at the moment.
Also I am aware of the [PlasticSCM](https://github.com/PlasticSCM/GuiTestSharp) solution but would like to "do it myself" if I can.

Comment: Generally speaking you don't "Unit Test a GUI". Unit Tests should be atomic and test methods. We rely on "Binding" the presentation tier to the business logic tier that way you don't need to test the GUI. You can still test the GUI that's fine, I just wanted to point out its a different thing.

Comment: This kind of test is not unit. It's a UI test and do it by your own might be very tricky and going low level (probably your code need a handler to the window just for starting)...  Basic UI tests are a screen automation, without help of a library of framewor the most complicated part of writing in on your own is not automate where to click but is capture the visual elements on the window you're testing. Did you check the sources of the library you mentioned?